# CSS Select Sibling of An Element with A Specific Sub-Element?

Tags: css, selector, parent, siblings

The snippet below is a part of a much larger structure with many .step elements.

I need to match all `.stepText` elements that are next to `.stepTitleAndImages ul.standard`

In other words, match all `.stepText` elements that have `.step` parent that has `.stepTitleAndImages` child that has `.stepImages.standard` child

```
<div class="step">
  <div class="stepTitleAndImages">
    <h3 class="stepTitle"></h3>
    <ul class="stepImages standard"></ul>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stepText "></div>  **HOW TO SELECT ALL ELEMENTS LIKE THIS ONE?**
  <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>

<div class="step">
  <div class="stepTitleAndImages">
    <h3 class="stepTitle"></h3>
    <ul class="stepImages medium"></ul>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stepText "></div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

PS: I cannot modify the HTML. Cannot use anything other than pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **cannot** be done with your HTML structure and with pure CSS. The closest solution to your problem, changing the HTML structure and with pure CSS, would be to move the `standard` class to its parent tag:

`<div class="stepTitleAndImages standard">
    <h3 class="stepTitle"></h3>
    <ul class="stepImages"></ul>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
  </div>`

This would allow you to use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (`+`), which matches **the second selector if it's the direct next sibling of the first**, like this:

`.stepTitleAndImages.standard + .stepText {
  /* Styles */
}`

A more flexible approach would be to use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) which would match **any sibling preceded by the first selector**, not only the direct next one:

`.stepTitleAndImages.standard ~ .stepText {
  /* Styles */
}`

The `:has` pseudo-class [is in development by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), but it hasn't hit any stable browsers yet. With it, and with your HTML structure, you could go:

`.stepTitleAndImages:has(.standard) + .stepText {
  /* Styles */
}`

Unfortunately, currently you can't solve this in any other way with CSS (and with your HTML structure) only.

Comment: Thanks for an elaborate answer Fausto NA. 
Unfortunately, I am (re)styling an external system here; no control over the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this for selecting first case

```
.step:nth-child(1) .stepText {
... Your CSS here
}
```

For second one use

```
.step:nth-child(2) .stepText {
... Your CSS here
}
```

For selecting both use

```
.step .stepText {
... Your CSS here
}
```

Then you should require jquery for that

Selecting Parents sibling is not possible only with pure CSS yet, You can achieve this by a single line of jquery:

```
$('ul.standard').parent().siblings(".stepText").css(...your CSS here);
```

Comment: Thanks you vkubre! Yet, I'm afraid I did not express myself clearly. Not your fault. 

The deal is to select all elements that correspond to this pattern, scattered across the source. I don't see how nth-child could do that. 

I have edited the question to reflect the true state.

Comment: Selecting Parents sibling is not possible only with pure CSS yet, You can achieve this by a single line of jquery:     
   **$('ul.standard').parent().siblings(".stepText").css('background','#f55');**   However if you know the pattern of .standard or .medium classes exactly then :nth-chlid(_your pattern formula here_) then you can achive this with pure CSS only

Comment: Thanks again @vkubre. 
This renders this specific project impossible. 
Cheers.